# Historical XMR price volatility compared to BTC

Tags: cryptocurrency-comparison, fiat

Where can I find historical volatility data comparing Monero with Bitcoin, measured against major fiat currencies (prefer data on EUR, GBP, AUD, NZD, USD, CAD, CHF, CNY or JPY) since the launch of Monero in 2014?

Secondly, where can I find volatility data for Bitcoin from the first two years following it's launch in 2008 to compare against the same data from the first two years of Monero trading?

Comment: There is a slight misspelling in the last sentence. "Yeats" should be "years". Since it is less than 6 characters, I am unable to perform the edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Poloniex.com is the largest market for Monero and maintains records for XMR and BTC price information which can be given in terms of USD via the symbol USDT.  This market-specific price information can be retrieved through their exchange tab or through the site's API [(example)](https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=BTC_XMR&start=1405699200&end=9999999999&period=14400).  Further API documentation can be found at https://poloniex.com/support/api/.

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin vol data can be found https://btcvol.info/